# Ruby On Rails Heroku DB Pointing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, heroku, database-migration

I am working on a ruby on rails project that is deployed on heroku. Very quickly I had a table in my database fill past the allowed 10,000 rows and had to upgrade to the paid version. I set up my new database and migrated all the rows from the old one by following the heroku step by step guide. The problem I'm having now is that my rails project is still pointing to the old table and not the upgraded one. How do I choose which one to point to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Heroku [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql):

**Establish primary DB**

Heroku recommends using the DATABASE_URL config var to store the location of your primary database. In single-database setups your new database will have already been assigned a HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COLOR_URL config with the accompanying DATABASE_URL. You may verify this via heroku config and verifying the value of both HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COLOR_URL and DATABASE_URL which should match.

On apps with multiple databases, you can set the primary database like so:

```
heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED
Promoting HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED_URL to DATABASE_URL... done
```